# Why I can't see signal values during simulation in Simulink? "no data yet" message

Tags: debugging, signals, simulink, display

I am trying to debug a Simulink model. For doing so, I've checked the option "Show When Hovering" in the "Display values" options. When I run the model I can see some signals and not others, which provide a "no data yet" message. However, as it can be seen in the attached screenshot, if I connect a display block this shows the actual value of the signal. So the signal has a value, it's just this is not display when hovering. How could I solve this?

I tried connecting a display block and could find out that the signal has a value.

Comment: Cannot see your _attached screenshot_

Comment: Some specialized signals can't be seen in debug mode, only standard simulink signals can be viewed. If you're using electrical signals, mechanical signals, or any other sort of physical signal you need a different tool

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons this may be the case:

1. You're trying to look at a "physical signal" or some other type of non-standard signal such as an electrical signal, or a mechanical signal.
   Solution: Use the "data inspector" tool instead (see below link) - this is an incredibly useful tool to get used to (scopes are cumbersome, and are far more limited). Even if this isn't your answer, I'd recommend getting used to this tool
   https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulationdatainspector.html
2. Your simulation hasn't run for long enough to log the signal
   Solution: just use the "step-forward" button in the simulation, which will move the simulation forward some steps, until eventually your signal will be logged and you'll see a value
3. You haven't logged the signal you want to see yet
   Solution: when in debug mode (run the simulation, and pause it before completion), click once on the signal and it should show up. Alternatively, click on the signal and go to the "signal" tab, then select "Output Value Label"